# Enviar 2 parámetros con JavaScript mediante AJAX a un método

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Estoy enviando con JavaScript una imagen canvas con `id=colors_sketch` de la siguiente manera:

```
function UploadPic() {
    var Pic = document.getElementById("colors_sketch").toDataURL("image/png");
    Pic = Pic.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "") 
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'Firma.aspx/UploadPic',
        data: '{ "imageData" : "' + Pic + '" }',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (msg) {
            alert("Correcto, Imagen Digitalizada Correctamente.");
        }
    });
}
```

El método `UploadPic` hecho en asp.net recibe la imagen.

```
Public Shared Sub UploadPic(imageData As String)

End Sub
```

Necesito ahora enviar también el contenido de un textBox que sea el NOMBRE de la imagen para utilizarlo de esta manera:

```
Public Shared Sub UploadPic(imageData As String, NOMBRE As String)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Lo haria asi:

```
function UploadPic() {
    var Pic = document.getElementById("colors_sketch").toDataURL("image/png");
    Pic = Pic.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "") 
    var usuario = document.getElementById("#id_text_box").value
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'Firma.aspx/UploadPic',
        data: '{ "imageData" : "' + Pic + '", "NOMBRE": "usuario" }',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (msg) {
            alert("Correcto, Imagen Digitalizada Correctamente.");
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solo modifica el objeto `data` así:

```
data: {
    imageData: Pic,
    NOMBRE: $("#textBox").val()
}
```